# iCal loads, but quits after a few seconds

Tags: ical

I added a calendar from my Google account in Ical and now it quit about 3 seconds after loading.

I have tried the solution described here:  https://discussions.apple.com/message/3680441#3680441
but I don't even have `user's Library > Application Support > iCal`

OS X 10.6.7

Comment: Just to clarify, are you literally trying to find a folder named `user's library`?

Comment: XD no.. `~/Library/Application\ Support/iCal` doesn't exist.

Comment: I figured that was what you meant, but I just wanted to be sure. I actually don't have that folder either. It looks like that discussion was about Tiger, not Snow Leopard.

Comment: I have also just tried to close iCal, moved `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iCal.plist` and `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iCal.helper.plist` to the Desktop and still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the same solution in the post you linked, but the calendars are stored in a different location (and format) in Snow Leopard. The calendars are stored as sub-folders of `~/Library/Calendars` in Snow Leopard.

If you have multiple calendars, you can check the date each folder was created to see which one would be the Google calendar.

Comment: Luckily, I didn't have any data stored locally so I just removed all contents in that folder. Thanks!